# Expression must have arithmetic type issue

Tags: c, math, matrix

I need to multiply two square matrixes A and B 15x15.
Unfortunately, I'm getting this kind of error.
I know the problem is in pointers while calculating matrix C.

```
        C[i][j] += *(A + k) * *(B + k)
```

I hope you can explain me what's wrong. I'm a beginner xD.
Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 15
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

int main() {
    int A[N][N];
    int B[N][N];
    int C[N][N];
    
    printf("Input matrix A.\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            printf("Enter your element:\n");
            scanf_s("%d", &A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("Input matrix B.\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            printf("Enter your element:\n");
            scanf_s("%d", &B[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    printf("Matrix A.\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("Matrix B.\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", B[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
            C[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < 14; k++) {
                C[i][j] += *(A + k) * *(B + k);
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Your result:\n");
    printf("Matrix C.\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", C[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't make life hard on yourself, just use `A[k]` not `*(A + k)`.

Comment: Hint: `A[k]` is a whole row. `A[k][n]` is a single element.

Comment: I have to use pointers :(

Comment: `A` is a pointer, so `A[k]` uses pointers by definition.

Comment: If you must inflict misery on yourself, consider how you'd index a single element in a 2D array. Hint: `k * N + j` The reason the `A[j][k]` notation is easier is because the pointer-math form becomes increasingly ridiculous as you add dimensions.

Comment: Aside: move `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` to the top - before including the libraries.

Comment: "this kind of error" -- what kind of error?

Answer (score 1):

The problem in the multiplication is that `A+k` and `B+k` have type `int (*)[15]` which means dereferencing it once only makes a pointer out of them; furthermore, you need to take row and column items individually, which means `A[i][k]` and `B[k][j]`, right? (also, there's no point on using confusing syntax, as the underlying operation is exactly the same).

Here's a fixed and improved version:

```c
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 15

/* Improvement 1 (type abstraction) */
typedef int NxN_int_matrix[N][N];

/* Improvement 2 (input function & wrapper) */
#define input_matrix(var) input_matrix_ex((var), #var)
static void input_matrix_ex(NxN_int_matrix dst, char *name)
{
    printf("Input matrix %s.\n", name);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            /* Improvement 3 (nicer prompt) */
            printf("%s[%2d][%2d]: ", name, i, j);
            fflush(stdout);
            scanf_s("%d", &dst[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

/* Improvement 4 (print function) */
#define print_matrix(var) print_matrix_ex(#var, (var))
static void print_matrix_ex(char *name, NxN_int_matrix M)
{
    printf("Matrix %s.\n", name);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", M[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

/* Improvement 5 (move multiplication to a function too, and fix it) */
static void mult_matrix(NxN_int_matrix dst, NxN_int_matrix a, NxN_int_matrix b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            /* Improvement 6 (don't write out intermediate values) */
            int tmp = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
                tmp += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
            dst[i][j] = tmp;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    NxN_int_matrix A, B, C;

    input_matrix(A);
    input_matrix(B);
    print_matrix(A);
    print_matrix(B);

    mult_matrix(C, A, B);

    printf("Your result:\n");
    print_matrix(C);

    return 0;
}

/* Possible further improvements:
 * - using a transposed B might make multiplication faster
 */
```